# MPMoviePlayer - entering fullscreen on iOS5 leaves stops playing and leaves screen black

Tags: ios, ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller

I just ran into a weird behaviour during my app-testing.
The app contains a videostream, played by a `MPMoviePlayer`, where when entering fullscreen (via button on the players controller) on iOS6 the screen goes blank and the movie stopps playing. On iOS5 the movie continues as expected.

I believe this would be a a bug in iOS6, and are therefore wondering:
 - Have anyone else experienced this behaviour?
 - Is it a bug in my code, or in the OS?
 - Any suggestions on how to deal with it?

On both phones the videostream plays as expected when the video is contained in a frame on screen (as a part of the view).
However when entering fullscreen they differ. I have filmed the behaviour on both phones.

On a relatively new iPhone 4S (running iOS 5.1.1) the following (expected) behaviour:
http://4340.no/ios5.mov

On an iPhone 3S (upgraded to iOS 6.0) the following (unexpected) behavour:
http://4340.no/ios6.mov

The code handling the playButton:

```
-(IBAction) playButtonClicked:(id)sender
{    
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.experiment.videoPath];
    self.mpController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [self.mpController prepareToPlay];
    self.mpController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 214);
    [self.view addSubview:self.mpController.view];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)                                                 
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:self.mpController];

    [self.mpController play];
}
```

Any tips or suggestions on how to solve this would be much appreciated.

**Post Mortem - code and explanation:**

Turns out `viewWillDisapear` and `viewDidDisappear` gets called when movie enters fullscreen on iOS6 (and not on iOS5).

The solution is to ensure that the `MPMovieplayerController` is not running `fullscreen` before dismissing the video player in either of these methods.

My new code then became:
(Note the `&& !self.mpController.fullscreen`

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(self.mpController && !self.mpController.fullscreen){
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
            removeObserver:self
            name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
         object:self.mpController];
        [self.mpController.view removeFromSuperview];
        self.mpController = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you doing anything in viewWillDisappear or viewDidDisappear that would cause the video to stop? That's what got me.

Comment: You are right. I am freeing the moviePlayer when the view do disapear.

Comment: So updating my check from `if(self.mpController)` to `if(self.mpController && !self.mpController.fullscreen)` before ditching the controller did fix this. I love when they change how stuf gets called :p

Comment: Upgraded my comment to an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're not stopping or releasing the video player in viewWillDisappear or viewDidDisappear.